# iTunes output goes exclusively to Airport Express when it should not

Tags: itunes, airport, airplay

My AirPlay setup is messed up since a few days : I have headsets plugged to an Airport Express (*AE*) and it used to play music synchronously with my macmini, as expected.

One day, while I did not do anything special, the macmini stopped to play music as soon as I switched on the *AE* headset, as if the music stream was redirected exclusively to the *AE*.
Yet, iTunes is properly configured in multiple sources mode :

[image: airplay sources]

If I uncheck the *Fabrice's Airport* source from iTunes and leave *Computer* as the only source, the problem remains : music still played exclusively by the *AE* ! Only switching off the *AE* makes the macmini emits the music again.

I tried unplug/replug the *AE* with no success.
Next step would be to reinitialize it but I'm open to others suggestions.

Comment: Hold ALT and click the music preferences on top of the menu bar. What output sources do you have selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the menu bar to see selected output device, I noticed that the Bluetooth icon was *ON* and thus interfering with Wifi Airplay.
By setting Bluetooth *OFF* on the mac mini, it corrected the problem.